# How to sort numbers containing current year in prefix

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am having trouble sorting the job numbers in my project.
My client requirement is to store the job numbers in the below format:-

```
current year-1, current year-2, current year-3, and so on...
```

For example:-
The current year is 2021 so the job number will be like this:-

```
21-1, 21-2, 21-3, 21-4, and so on...
```

When the year changes it should start again from 1 and so on for the next year.
For example:-

```
22-1, 22-2, 22-3, 22-4, and so on...
```

I had stored the job numbers in the above format successfully but I am unable to sort the job numbers in the correct way as required by the client.
I had sorted the data in this way:-

```
21-1, 21-10, 21-100 to 21-109, 21-11 to 21-19, 21-2 and so on...
```

but the actual sort should be like this:-

```
21-1, 21-2, 21-3, 21-4...21-10, 21-11 to 21-99, 21-100 to 21-199 and so on...
```

And if the year changes then:-

```
22-1, 22-2, 22-3, 22-4...22-10, 22-11 to 22-99, 22-100 to 22-199 and so on...
```

I hope I have explained my problem briefly. Please help me in sorting out the job numbers.

Comment: Please include the code you used to sort this data in your updated question

Comment: Use natcase sorting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need the sorting to occur in your database because you're paging or just otherwise not holding all results in application memory, use use the following sql `order by` clause:

```
select    my_column
from      my_table
order by  left(my_column, 2),
          len(my_column),
          right(my_column, len(my_column) - 2)
```

**Explanation:**

1. `left(my_column, 2),` numerically sort first two digits so years are grouped together.
2. `len(my_column)` group record sequence based on magnitude (i.e., `xx-100` appears after `xx-2` because it's longer).
3. `right(my_column, len(my_column) - 2)` numerically sort record sequence.

Hint: This assumes your year-code is always exactly two digits. I could have found the index of the dash instead, but that feels even more presumptive.

---

If you require an application-side (PHP) solution, you can use [natsort](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_natsort.asp). From W3Schools:

> **Definition and Usage**
>
> The natsort() function sorts an array by using a
> "natural order" algorithm. The values keep their original keys.
>
> In a natural algorithm, the number 2 is less than the number 10. In
> computer sorting, 10 is less than 2, because the first number in "10"
> is less than 2.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> natsort(array)

Comment: Thank you, Devin Burke. Your answer is working fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
21-1, 21-10, 21-100, 1, 10, 100
```

These are your ids from the database. At first, declare an empty array and a variable for serial then loop through the objects. Push every object with two new `keys array["date_serial"]`, `array["serial"]`. Then take the new array and then display the result by sorting the array by "serial" key or `asc` or `desc` order.